# How to get DBpedia entity by using keywords?

Tags: dictionary, dbpedia

I'm implementing `keyword based entity search system` for `DBpedia`. For the algorithm I need correct candidates for keywords, for example if I have keyword `Bill` I need to have http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#Bill_Gates. Currently, I'm using `Lucene` and if the entity has `label` or `name` I map this entity to this label/name. But, in this case it produces a lot of unintended candidates. For preventing it I'm applying `String similarity check` but still it not as successful as it should be. Thus, looking for efficient way to get correct entities with the given keywords.

Comment: Possibly you don't need to write this from scratch, as something very much like it is [already provided](http://dbpedia.org/fct/) by the [Facet Browser](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtFacetBrowserInstallConfig) implemented on the public [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) instance hosting DBpedia… (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of Virtuoso.)

Comment: @TallTed thanks for this. Is it have possiblility to use with Java? If yes, how is it?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, so I cannot say whether it is possible with Java or otherwise. You might consider writing to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), including as much additional detail as possible…